# NU1605 Detected package downgrade error when try the Publish project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, version, publish

I'm trying to Publish my project because I will live the project. But when I try to publish my project I get `NU1605  Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore from 2.1.14 to 2.1.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. MyTravelBlogs -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.25 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.1.14 && < 2.2.0) MyTravelBlogs -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.1.1)` 
and the same error for

`NU1605  Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools from 2.1.14 to 2.1.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. MyTravelBlogs -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.25 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (>= 2.1.14 && < 2.2.0) MyTravelBlogs -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (>= 2.1.1)`

Here is my csproj file

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebStackScaffolding_IsLayoutPageSelected>True</WebStackScaffolding_IsLayoutPageSelected>
    <WebStackScaffolding_IsPartialViewSelected>False</WebStackScaffolding_IsPartialViewSelected>
    <WebStackScaffolding_IsReferencingScriptLibrariesSelected>False</WebStackScaffolding_IsReferencingScriptLibrariesSelected>
    <WebStackScaffolding_ViewDialogWidth>600</WebStackScaffolding_ViewDialogWidth>
    <Controller_SelectedScaffolderID>MvcControllerEmptyScaffolder</Controller_SelectedScaffolderID>
    <Controller_SelectedScaffolderCategoryPath>root/Controller</Controller_SelectedScaffolderCategoryPath>
    <WebStackScaffolding_ControllerDialogWidth>600</WebStackScaffolding_ControllerDialogWidth>
    <WebStackScaffolding_IsAsyncSelected>False</WebStackScaffolding_IsAsyncSelected>
    <WebStackScaffolding_LayoutPageFile>~/Views/Shared/_myLayout.cshtml</WebStackScaffolding_LayoutPageFile>
    <NameOfLastUsedPublishProfile>FolderProfile</NameOfLastUsedPublishProfile>
    <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I tried to add `<TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>` to csproj file which people did in other questions but it doesn't work. I did not try to change versions of Nugets because I think it will create other problems about launching my project. How can I fix that and publish my project successfully? Thanks

Comment: Check the dependencies of all nugets and referenced projects, one should be pointing to the older and other to the newer version of that package. Try to keep the same version referenced by all projects.

Comment: Do ı need to manage this in csproj ?

Comment: Change the target version of project to Core 2.1 instead of Core 2.2.

Comment: In csproj you can see the directly referenced nugets, but to see the dependencies of the nugets just use the solution explorer, expand Dependencies and look under Packages and Projects for the dependencies of each nuget and project.

Comment: @jdweng dotnet.com says the 2.2 version has end of life, no longer supported

Comment: @LazZiya no you say ı need to edit packages for every package has the same version right?

Comment: See which packages are using different versions of the same referenced nuget, then try to make all using the same version.

Comment: The NUGET is at Core 2.1.  So either you have to set your project to target 2.1 or you upgrade the NUGET to newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with same issue but I recovered using this magic line. You may try in your project. Hope you get well.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="2.2.0" ExcludeAssets="all" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning all the nuget packages cache worked for me.

To clear it, in VStudio go to Tools > Package Manager Settings and then click the "Clear All NuGet Storage" button.